# Shortest path by minimum number of vertices

Tags: graph, dijkstra, shortest-path, directed-graph, floyd-warshall

I have read about Floyd and Dijkstra, but they to find shortest path by minimum length of edges between nodes

How can I find the shortest path in a directed graph by traversing the minimum number of nodes?

Comment: Give each edge a weight of 1...

Answer (score 1):

Trivial way:

Assign equal weights to all edges.

No. of edges = total weight of path / weight of each edge.

No. of nodes = No. of edges + 1 (or - 1 if you don't count the ends).

Comment: how about i take a conventional dijkstra and swop the nodes and edges. then search for shortest path.

Comment: @Roy _swap_ them? woz meenz?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize number of vertices traversed. So if I represent the vertices as edges in this graph (and edges as vertices) then I can proceed to calculate the shortest path using dijkstra right?

Comment: @Roy dijkstra considers weights so unless your edges are weighted as above (or alter the implementation - non-trivial), it'll just be equivalently invalid

Comment: Yeah, would it work if I assigned the edges a weight of 1? Acc to this, seems like it could...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048446/is-dijkstras-algorithm-optimal-for-unweighted-graphs

Comment: @Roy that's the best way coz you wouldn't have to divide by anything, but any weight will do (apart from 0 of course :-])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50237843/1647320 Your question has a detailed answer here.