# Find a minimum in a list of shortest paths

Tags: python, graph

I have my graph object, im trying to find a method to find a minimum for a group of nodes.

Ex. Nodes:

```
      input_nodes=[123,45]
      graph_nodes=[10, 76,123,45,98,456]
```

I  run an algoritm which calculate shortest path between every node in the graph and every node in the input. 
 I have a dictionary with all shortest paths beetwen nodes :

```
                {10:{123:0.56, 45:0.2}, 76:{123:0, 45:0.23}......
```

and so on for every graphs node. 
How to get only min weight which is different from zero:

Like this:

Minimum path node 10 has with node 45,
Minimum path node 76 has with node 45, 
......
Thatnks

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164397/find-the-min-max-excluding-zeros-in-a-numpy-array-or-a-tuple-in-python?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there might be ties in the weights, i.e. one node can be equally "close" to more than one other node. The following code will include them all in a dict. The structure of the result is essentially the same as the input `d`, but only the minimum weight items are retained.

**Update**: if a node has no neighbors or only neighbors with weight 0, this node will map to a empty dict in the result.

```
d = {10:{123:0.56, 45:0.2}, 76:{123:0, 45:0.23}, 19:{17:0}, 20:{}}

def closest(ns):
    m = min((v for v in ns.values() if v != 0), default=-1)
    return {k: v for k, v in ns.items() if v == m}

print({k: closest(v) for k, v in d.items()})
```

Comment: It says : min argument is an empty sequence

Comment: So you have elements in `d` that have no or only 0 weight neighbors. I've adapted the code. Note that `default=` is only supported since Python 3.4.

Comment: Your question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50237843/1647320